# Cloud Run ARM64 support

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, arm64

Using the following image

```
FROM sitespeedio/node:ubuntu-20.04-nodejs-16.15.1
```

With `docker build --platform linux/amd64`

Works great!

--

But, when switching to the ARM64 version.

```
FROM arm64v8/node:16.18.1
```

with `--platform linux/arm/v8`

I get the following error

```
terminated: Application failed to start: invalid status ::14: could not start container: exec format error
```

From the Cloud container logs

[image]

Running the image locally on my machine, both of them work great. So not really sure where to go now. There's no documentation on this that I can find.

Note* I have an M1 Macbook Pro, our build machines are also M1s, ARM64 speeds up the build process by around 15x and the server costs are lower apparently.

Comment: AFAIK Cloud Run does not supoort ARM architechtures. Apparently gVisor does https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/faq/ in preliminary (which is used in CR) but maybe is not yet implemented in Cloud Run

Comment: @Ferregina thanks I see that GCP has ARM options for other features. I guess they will implement this option at somepoint for Cloud Run? Other cloud providers have it on their serverless options (AWS and Azure)

Comment: Hopefully yes. Anyway you can create a Feature Request here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0 for that

Comment: @Ferregina indeed it's being worked on here https://github.com/google/gvisor/milestone/2

Comment: I created a [feature request for arm64](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303743857).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Ferregina, Currently CloudSDK does not support any ARM64-based images. And it is also confirmed by Google team member on your post [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Does-Cloud-Run-support-ARM64/m-p/496958).

As suggested by them you can raise feature request.

If you wish to use `cloud run emulator` check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072262/18265570).